# Django 3.0: django-notifications giving error: "Notification.recipient" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-views, pypi, django-notification

I am using django-notifications-hq package [link of django-notifications-hq](https://pypi.org/project/django-notifications-hq/) and getting error:

> Cannot assign "<Seller: john@gmail.com>":
> "Notification.recipient" must be a "User" instance.

my custom `user` model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

my `seller` model having 1to1 relation with `user`:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic/seller', null=True, blank=True)
```

my `Book` model has foreign key `seller`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='book_written_by')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField('Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
```

And somewhere in my `views` after successfully getting `books` just bought by some user, I want to notify all respective `sellers` that someone has bought their book:

```
for book in books:
     notify.send(Seller, recipient=book.seller, verb="User has just bought book named {} priced 
                                                             as {}".format(book.title, book.price))
```

I know it works fine `recipient = request.user` but I have different scenario. How can I make `book.seller` a `User` instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a super simple solution.  You're 99% of the way there!

Instead of this:

```
for book in books:
     notify.send(Seller, recipient=book.seller, verb="User has just bought book named {} priced 
                                                             as {}".format(book.title, book.price))
```

Try this:

```
for book in books:
     notify.send(book.seller.user, recipient=book.seller.user, verb="User has just bought book named {} priced 
                                                             as {}".format(book.title, book.price))
```

The `Seller` has a property called `user` but it isn't a `user` itself.

Comment: I went to try your suggestion but I am getting this `Field 'id' expected a number but got '<property object at 0x0000020F13765B88>'`. I don't know what I have done it doesn't let me open /admin/notifications/notification/ through `django admin`. Through admin I am getting same error.

Comment: I am re-reading the docs and it seems like you're supposed to supply a user group, user queryset, or list of users.  Maybe try `recipient=[book.seller.user, ]` instead?  It also seems like you could try `notify.send(book.seller.user, recipient=book.seller.user...)` but their docs are a bit confusing. https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications#generating-notifications

Comment: Yeah but this error `Field 'id' expected a number but got '<property object at 0x0000020F13765B88>` is not going away. I have commented out all the code related to `notifications` and even uninstalled app. Then I installed it again but this error is not going away at /admin/notifications/notification/ through django admin. Help me how to delete this table from `db` and install it again.

Comment: I got my `db` back. But what about solution of my query. Have you figured it out ?

Comment: I'm not sure what went wrong there.  You haven't given much info on the nature of the problem, or what you changed.  If you've commented out all the notifications package code then it seems likely that the problem lies in your non-notification code somehow.

Comment: `notify.send(book.seller.user, recipient=book.seller.user...)` this worked. Edit your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Awesome great!  Sorry we didn't get it 100% right the first time.